# Derivative of the composition of functions $z = x \sin xy, ~x= \ln (u^2 - 1), ~y = -\sqrt{1 - v^2}$

Tags: derivatives

I'm just confused facing this type of task. Should I just calculate derivatives of sub-functions and solve the main one using this data?

Comment: Derivative of what with respect to what?

Answer (score 4):

Given the suggestion of the question, I would imagine that you are looking for $\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}.$ The key aspect of this problem is that we must use the multivariable chain rule. In particular,

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial u} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}0 = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}.$$

Similarly,

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial v} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial v} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}0 + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}.$$

I would imagine that you could quickly compute $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial x}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial y}{\partial v},$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ on your own given the functions available.

From quick calculations, I see that

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = sin(xy) + x\cos(xy)y$$
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} = \frac{1}{u^2 -1} \times 2u$$
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = x^2\cos(xy)$$
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial v} = -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-v^2}} \times (-2v)
= \frac{v}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}.$$